# Print an array of only the first cells

Tags: typescript

I have array that i want to make print but with only with the frist cells .

this is my array :

```
var arr = [ {x: 123, y:987}, {x: 456, y:654}, {x: 789,  y:100200300}, {x: 101112, y:400500600} ];
```

I want to print :

```
123,456,789,101112
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: With a loop. Shouldn't be that hard, just give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use with the function `map()` , try this :

```
console.log(arr.map(item => item.x));
```

The output :

```
Array(4)
0: 123
1: 456
2: 789
3: 101112
```

Now you can print in as you want ..